# killing loaded view before load another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am loading four different views using query. It is working fine for loading only. Now I want to kill the loaded view before loading new one. For example, when website is loaded, the first view is loaded. Then when user clicks any other link then before loading second view the first view should killed first before the new one is loaded. How can I achieve this. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
<style type="text/css">
.header { width: 100%; height: 50px; background: lightblue; }
.header ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
.header ul li { float: left; margin-right: 50px; }
.container { width: 100%; height: 500px; background: lightgreen; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.container').load('viewone.html');
        $('.header ul li a').click(function() {
            var el = $(this).attr('rel');
            $('.container').load(el + '.html');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='header'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" rel='viewone'>Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel='viewtwo'>Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel='viewthree'>Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel='viewfour'>Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class='container'>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could load everything at the same time and hide the ones not currently being used using:

```
 $('thing').hide();
```

When you want to show attach this:

```
$('thing').show();
```

to you click element.

I would also perhaps load each thing in a new element to make things a bit easier.

Comment: But I want to remove previous view completely from memory. How can I do that?

Comment: instead of hide, you can do .remove()

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('.container').load('viewone.html');
        $('.header ul li a').click(function() {
            var el = $(this).attr('rel');
             $('.container').empty();
            $('.container').load(el + '.html');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to call the following code:

```
$('.container').empty();
```